# C++ compilation issues on local and TFS

Tags: c++, tfs

I have a mixed Visual Studio solution that contains C++ projects, C# projects and VB.NET projects.

My first issues is regarding the compilation :

1. First I select a rebuild solution it clears all projects and starts building everything (which is totally fine)
2. After that i select a build solution again and it builds again all projects. I would expect that it knows that nothing changed (especially on the C++ projects that take a lot of time to compile) . First i thought that this is because of the PCH files. So, I enabled the PCH files on some of the C++ projects, but stil the same happens . Is my expectation correct or not ?

The second issue is regardind my TFS 2013 build on this solution.
I would like to have the C++ projects outputed to a separate directory on the build machine. I have configured my out directories in my C++ projects and on the local machine everything is as expected, but on the build machine everything is under the same directory. 
I tries some solution as the following : [link](https://blog.stangroome.com/2012/02/03/override-the-tfs-team-build-outdir-property/)

but for C++ projects this won't work.

Can someone help me on these issues ?

Comment: You'd better post only one issue for one thread. In this way, our discussion here will be much more targeted and won't confused.

Comment: Could you share your build process template file on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

**For the second issue about TFS**

In the build definition, you should confirm that if the **Configurations** are set the same with local place. If they're not the same, change it.

You also need to set the **Output location** to **AsConfigured** in the build definition.

[image]

[image]

**For the first issue**, I suggest that you'd better post a new question and add the corresponding tags for dedicated help. I have found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563289/how-can-i-automaticly-compile-only-projects-that-have-changed-when-i-build-my-so), maybe you can try to use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) tool to help you.

Comment: I am using TFS 2013 and in my Process panel i don't have the options you mentioned.

Comment: @Lucian I'm using TFS 2013 Update5, did you use the default template? The second picture is a screenshot of the project property not for build definition.

Comment: I am using the template VersioningBuildTemplate20.xaml

Comment: @Lucian Is that your custom build template, you'd better use the default build template[TfvcTemplate.12.xaml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUVvsAxVun9SbElg).